# Reporte hecho en crystal report me cambia el tamaño del papel de impresora térmica

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tengo un reporte hecho en Crystal Report de una factura que deseo imprimir con una impresora Térmica marca Epson TM-88V, el tamaño del papel lo definí vía código el que necesito que me hale, pero por defecto me pone el papel 8½x11 tamaño carta cuando debería de ser 80x297 mm.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy usando para forzar el tamaño predeterminado es este:

```
var doctoPrint = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
doctoPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T88V Receipt"; 

for (var j = 0; j < doctoPrint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; j++)
if (doctoPrint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[j] .PaperName == "Roll Paper 80 x 297 mm") 
{
      report.PrintOptions.PaperSize =  
      (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)doctoPrint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[j].RawKind;
      break;
}
```

Espero que me entiendan y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Estas cambiando el tamaño del papel en tiempo de ejecución, tu diseñador no conoces el tamaño,por eso asigna ese tipo. Puedes establecer tu tamaño dándole con el botón derecho del ratón en el informe y luego diseño

Comment: @Juanjo Gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo intenté así, inclusive asocié la impresora y el tamaño de papel al reporte y cuando lo genero tiene el mismo tamaño carta para imprimir, esto provoca que no salga el reporte al enviarlo.

Answer (score 0):

También tengo algunos reportes con Crystal Reports y la solución que utilizo para los casos como el que tu planteas, es cambiar el tamaño de papel predeterminado en la configuración de la impresora en windows.

Aunque los casos con los que he tenido que lidiar no son específicos de la impresora Epson TM-88V, siempre me ha funcionado con otros modelos de impresoras Epson y también impresoras de otras marcas.